# How can I create a textbox that opens Google search in a Windows application with CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a CefSharp WPF application and I need a textbox that will open Google searching the query in the application without closing and reopening it.

I'm working on it for something. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is achievable if you use CefSharpBrowser control.

There is a browser implemented in WPF in [this sample:](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example).
This constructor logic from the same sample should help you to get started:

```
public BrowserTabViewModel(string address)
        {
            Address = address;
            AddressEditable = Address;

            GoCommand = new RelayCommand(Go, () => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Address));
            HomeCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddressEditable = Address = CefExample.DefaultUrl);
            ExecuteJavaScriptCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(ExecuteJavaScript, s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
            EvaluateJavaScriptCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(EvaluateJavaScript, s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
            ShowDevToolsCommand = new RelayCommand(() => webBrowser.ShowDevTools());
            CloseDevToolsCommand = new RelayCommand(() => webBrowser.CloseDevTools());
            JavascriptBindingStressTest = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                WebBrowser.Load(CefExample.BindingTestUrl);
                WebBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += (e, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.IsLoading == false)
                    {
                        Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                            WebBrowser.Reload();
                        });
                    }
                };
            });

            PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;

            var version = string.Format("Chromium: {0}, CEF: {1}, CefSharp: {2}", Cef.ChromiumVersion, Cef.CefVersion, Cef.CefSharpVersion);
            OutputMessage = version;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!